# When i give the output as no it is coming Use umbrella

Tags: python

> dont know see the output by doing it no.
> When i give the output as no it is coming Use umbrella

```
str(input("Is it raining: "))
if("Yes" or "yes"):
    print("Use Umbrella")
elif("no" or "No"):
    print("No need of Umbrella")
else:
    print("Invalid option")
```

Comment: How do you think the user's input is related to those conditions? After that, note that e.g. `"Yes" or "yes"` just evaluates to `"Yes"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add lower() to transform your string to lower case and reduce duplication of 'Yes, yes or YES'

```
inp = str(input("Is it raining: ")).lower()
if inp == 'yes':
    print("Use Umbrella")
elif inp == 'no':
    print("No need of Umbrella")
else:
    print("Invalid option")
```

Answer (score -3):

i think you need somthing like this

```py
inp = str(input("Is it raining: "))
if inp in ("Yes" or "yes"):
    print("Use Umbrella")
elif inp in("no" or "No"):
    print("No need of Umbrella")
else:
    print("Invalid option")
```

Comment: Instead of `inp in ("Yes" or "yes")`, `inp in ("Yes", "yes")` because `("Yes" or "yes")` evaluates to `"Yes"`